# Major power shift in Gaul circa 350 B.C

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, france, archaeology, celts

I realize this is a little before history and therefore interpretive. I recall reading something about a shift that took place in Gaul, some time before the Romans came there. It may have been around 350 B.C. It involved a major tribe in central Gaul which was more or less dominant. Their capitol was sacred to the Celts, so much so that it was spared in major wars. I believe it may have been the capitol of druidry. Then there was a shift and another people, i think they were from the north, overtook them. I'm sure La Tene was involved in this somehow, where they the newcomers? the dispossed people may have formed a part of the celtic invasion of Italy. Maybe it was the Averni? Am I making this all up?

Added: The biturgies were influential in druidry, and Avaricum (Bourges) was the city that Vercingterox did not burn. I'm not talking about his era, but highlighting the importance of the city. Did the Biturgies displace an earlier people from Avaricum?

Comment: Conflict between Rome and Gaul goes back much further than people think. Gallic forces under [Brennus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brennus_(4th_century_BC)) defeated the Romans in the [Battle of the Allia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Allia) in about 390 BC.

Comment: The article on [Avaricum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0006:entry=avaricum) in The Princeton Encyclopedia of Classical Sites offers a brief overview of what is known about Avaricum from archaeology.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think you're making this up except I'm slightly confused because the ***period does not match***.

Is it **[Ambigatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambicatus)**, the first King of Bituriges?

He is placed within **[early La-Tene culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_T%C3%A8ne_culture#Periodization)**, (*6th century BCE*). And he did instruct his nephews, Bellovesus and Segovesus, to migrate out of **[Avaricum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avaricum)** (present-day Bourges) because there were too many for Ambigatus to rule at their citadel, Avaricum.

> Ambigatus was king at that time, a man eminent for his own personal courage and prosperity as much as for those of his dominions. During his sway the harvests were so abundant and the population increased so rapidly in Gaul that the government of such vast numbers seemed almost impossible. He was now an old man, and anxious to **relieve his realm from the burden of over-population**. With this view he signified his intention of sending his sister's sons Bellovesus and Segovesus, both enterprising young men, to settle in whatever locality the gods should by augury assign to them. They were to invite as many as wished to accompany them, sufficient to prevent any nation from repelling their approach. When the auspices were taken, the **Hercynian forest was assigned to Segovesus; to Bellovesus the gods gave the far pleasanter way into Italy**.

**Source**: Livy, ***[Liv. 5 34](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0026%3Abook%3D5%3Achapter%3D34)***

If it is Ambigatus, the Celts should be the first ones at Avaricum (i.e. Bourges), because he was the first *high king*, i.e. King of Gaul.

By the way, I wonder if Bituriges is from Welsh, "***byd***" which should be "**world**" and Latin, "***rex***" which is "**king**"? Hence, King of the World?

See also **[Bituriges (early Celts)](http://www.historyfiles.co.uk/KingListsEurope/BarbarianBituriges.htm)**.